# Best approach to use data from different APIs in PHP file or WP template

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I need an advice what best approach to connect APIs from different sources to some template/page and to not make duplicates of these pages for each API I connected?

To make it clear what I want:
For example I have some API `X` and some API `Y` and some Template `tpl.php` where I would like to display some data from these APIs. Lets say I would like to display `name` property of returned item from APIs. In API `X` this property could be named `item_name` and in `Y` this property could be just `name` or even in another path. As I understand to avoid situation where I'll create hundreds of conditions for each API and duplicates of templates for each API I have to write some class - wrapper lets say `Z` where I specify properties for each API and will call in my `tpl.php` as `Z->name`.

I searched for something like this but nothing found. Also how to call similar class - wrapper and to find some examples?

Comment: [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Comment: I know how to include template. How this feature would help me to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a BEST solution but it should do.

First come up with a unified format, which you will put in the `AppItemInterface`

Create two classes which reflect Item and follow the same `AppItemInterface`. (meaning they each have `getName` and `setName` methods, for example)

so:

```
class ApiXItem implements AppItemInterface{}
```

and

```
class ApiYItem implements AppItemInterface{}
```

`AppItemInterface` should contain a method `getInstance($sourceData)`

each of the Api classes will use `getInstance` implementation to put correct values to the `ApiXItem` class and `ApiYItem` `$name` property.

Once the properties are set, you can add a method `toArray` within interface (and Api classes to follow the interface) which will return unified format in each of them. In this case an array with `name` key in both classes

once you have an unified format you can do things like `array_merge` on two of them in the order you prefer.

That's just one of the methods, but should be a good start ;)